# How to create lines, circles in stageXL?

Tags: dart, stagexl

I'm just new to stagexl, I know these are very basic questions, but I couldn't find an answer real quick, so I thought it would be nice to have this answered for anybody in the same position as I am.

How do I create a line from x to y in stagexl ?

And how do I create a circle with center x and radius y ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the Shape display object. To draw a circle you just need to write this code:

```
var shape = new Shape();
shape.graphics.beginPath();
shape.graphics.circle(100, 100, 50);
shape.graphics.closePath();
shape.graphics.fillColor(Color.Red);
stage.addChild(shape);
```

To draw a line you have to do this:

```
var shape = new Shape();
shape.graphics.beginPath();
shape.graphics.moveTo(50, 50);
shape.graphics.lineTo(250, 150);
shape.graphics.closePath();
shape.graphics.strokeColor(Color.Red);
stage.addChild(shape);
```

You can learn more about it here:

http://www.stagexl.org/docs/wiki-articles.html?article=graphics

Please keep in mind that vector shapes are currently only supported with the Canvas2D renderer in StageXL. We are currently working on the WebGL renderer implementation too. You can use Shapes with the WebGL renderer too, if you use the applyCache method on the Shape. This will draw the Shape to a texture which can be used in WebGL too. This is also a much faster way to draw vector graphics.

Comment: Who is the "we" in " *we* are working on..."? (I know: your profile says you are one of the developers. But this answer could be better by expanding a bit on that. As it is, the "we" seems a bit out of place. :)

Comment: see https://github.com/bp74/StageXL/graphs/contributors for the contributors @Jongware

Comment: @Kasper: well it's more that SO is a Question + Answer site. Think of an encyclopedia- you would not find a "we" in an explanation there.

Comment: @bp74 thanks for your answer, so basicly if I don't need it to be really fast, the easiest way is to just set the stage in this way:


`Stage stage = new Stage(querySelector('#stage'), options: new StageOptions()..renderEngine = RenderEngine.Canvas2D);`

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of this @Jongware. I'm not experienced in answering questions on StackOverflow but i will learn. I think the first priority is answering the questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example, that you can also clone from gist if you want to try it out: https://gist.github.com/kasperpeulen/5cd660b5088311c64872

I'm not really sure if I do the WebGL example correct though, it seems like the WebGL graphic is blurry if I do it in this way.

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'package:stagexl/stagexl.dart';

main() {
  initWebGL();
  initCanvas2D();
}

initWebGL() {
  Stage stage = new Stage(html.querySelector('#WebGL'));
  new RenderLoop().addStage(stage);

  stage.addChild(circle(new Point(100, 100), 50));
  stage.addChild(line(new Point(50, 50), new Point(250, 150)));
  stage.applyCache(0,0,stage.sourceWidth,stage.sourceHeight);
}

initCanvas2D() {
  Stage stage = new Stage(html.querySelector('#Canvas2D'),
      options: new StageOptions()..renderEngine = RenderEngine.Canvas2D);
  new RenderLoop().addStage(stage);

  stage.addChild(circle(new Point(100, 100), 50));
  stage.addChild(line(new Point(50, 50), new Point(250, 150)));
}

Shape line(Point from, Point to, {color: Color.Black}) {
  return new Shape()
    ..graphics.beginPath()
    ..graphics.moveTo(from.x, from.y)
    ..graphics.lineTo(to.x, to.y)
    ..graphics.closePath()
    ..graphics.strokeColor(color);
}

Shape circle(Point<num> point, num radius, {color: Color.Black}) {
  return new Shape()
    ..graphics.beginPath()
    ..graphics.circle(point.x, point.y, radius)
    ..graphics.closePath()
    ..graphics.fillColor(color);
}
```